# Can airflow be used to run a never ending task?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Can we use an airflow dag to define a never-ending job (ie. a task which has a unconditional loop to consume stream data) by setting the task/dag timeout to None and manually trigger its running? Would having airflow monitor a never ending task cause a problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit odd to run this through Airflow, but yeah I don't think that's an issue. Just note that if you restart the worker running the job (assuming CeleryExecutor), you'll interrupt the task and need to kick it off manually again if `retries` is not set. Also make sure the DAG sets `execution_timeout=None` (default).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sensor which monitors if "data exists", then triggers a dag which does some processing. Is this what you wanted? please let me know.

Comment: Not really.  Thanks for your response, but the use case is a true consuming of streaming logs.  The previous response is what I was looking for.